# BadOptionError when import volatility.conf

Tags: python, exception, volatility

I write below code and it gives me error in first line! whats wrong is with this code:

```
import volatility.conf as conf
import volatility.registry as reg
import volatility.commands as commands
import volatility.addrspace as addrspace
import volatility.plugins.taskmods as taskmode



# configure volatility
reg.PluginImporter()
config=conf.ConfObject()
reg.register_global_options(conf,commands.Command)
reg.register_global_options(conf,addrspace.BaseAddressSpace)

config.parse_options()
config.PROFILE="Linuxfedora32x64"
config.LOCATION="./dumps/mem.lime"

p=taskmode.PSList(config)
for process in p.calculate:
    print(process)
```

the error code:i think there is some code insode conf.py witch in not support in python 3.6 .but volatility is copatible with python 3.6. so i don't know what to do :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../PycharmProjects/volpractive/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    import volatility.conf as conf
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/volatility-2.6-py3.6.egg/volatility/conf.py", line 84
    except (optparse.BadOptionError, optparse.OptionValueError), err:
```

Comment: Could you post the whole traceback? The problem doesn't seem to be in the code. Might be in a conf file which is automatically loaded when `conf` module is imported?

Comment: @CristiFati i edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right, the line:

```
except (optparse.BadOptionError, optparse.OptionValueError), err:
```

is not *Python3* compatible (according to [[Python]: The try statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#except)).

According to [[GitHub]: volatilityfoundation/volatility - (2.6) volatility/README.txt:*126+*](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility/blob/2.6/README.txt#L126) (**as it is at this point**):

> Requirements
>   ============
>   - Python **2.6** or later, but **not 3.0**. http://www.python.org

**Note**:

- The stacktrace is still incomplete (missing the last line - should be `SyntaxError`); that would have cleared things up much sooner

So, you have to run it with *Python2.6+* (of course you could also modify the code (at least the part that you need) to be *Python3* compatible, but I doubt that's feasible).